# Resizable html report

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services, telerik-reporting

We’ve been looking for reporting components, and we’re having difficulty a report designer that will render reports properly on both phones and computers. We want the report to display in the same way on different screen sizes (desktop and phone), or at the very least, display on both without clipping on the phone. Our thought is the easiest way to lay out such a report is for the report designer to specify table and column sizes as a percent of the width (sort of like HTML tables) rather than hardcoded pixel sizes. So when my page is resized, my report (and content elements) also gets resized, and it continues to fit.

We tried Telerik Reporting but unfortunately they don’t support this feature. They also don’t support the feature where report is resized when window is resized. The size you lay out is the size it is. They indicated they have something that will come out in beta soon, but have given us very few details. We tried the demo for Infragistics, and it seems to have the same limitations.

Is there anything else in the development space that will allow us to produce reports with more “fluid” layout, or in the very least, zoom in on the phone instead of clipping?

Comment: I think in order to do this you would need to be able to use CSS to style the objects in your report. With CSS you could create the dynamic, liquid layout that you're after. However, after a brief bit of googling it doesn't seem like there is a way to use CSS in an SSRS report. If you find out how to do it I for one would be very interested in knowing how you pulled this off.

Comment: will this help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345247.aspx

Answer (score 0):

is twitter [bootstrap](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/bootstrap-twitter) an option? tb supports responsive design  which will make easier to adapt your report to any device, you just will need to adapt your media queries

kendo ui supports responsive design you may [take a look](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-01-22/responsive_design_with_twitter_bootstrap.aspx), if bootstrap is an overkill you should try a separate [jquery UI or JS library](http://speckyboy.com/2011/10/24/25-jquery-plugins-to-help-with-responsive-layouts/) that helps you out with a fluid layout

hope that helps